# Populate one column based on the previous values of another

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to create a column which populates the transaction ID for every row up until the row where that transaction was completed - in this example every "add to basket" event before an order.

So far I have tried using `FIRST_VALUE`:

```
SELECT 
UserID, date, session_id, hitnumber, add_to_basket, transactionid, 
first_value(transactionid) over (partition by trans_part order by date, transactionid) AS t_id
FROM(
  select UserID, date, session_id, hitnumber, add_to_basket, transactionid, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN transactionid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY date, transactionid) AS trans_part,
  FIRST_VALUE(transactionid IGNORE NULLS) 
OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY hitnumber ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS t_id,
  from q1
  join q2 using (session_id)
  order by 1,2,3,4
)
```

But the result I am getting is the inverse of what I want, populating the transaction ID of the previous order against the basket events which happened after this transaction.

How can I change my code so that I will see the transaction id of the order AFTER the basket events that led up to it? For example, in the table below I want to see the transaction id ending in ...095 instead of the id ending in ...383 for the column `t_id`.

[image]

Based on Gordon's answer below I have also tried:

```
last_value(transactionid ignore nulls) over(
  order by hitnumber 
  rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as t_id2,
```

But this is not populating the event rows which proceed a transaction with a transaction id (seen below as `t_id2`):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `last_value(ignore nulls)`:

```
select . . . ,
       last_value(transaction_id ignore nulls) over (
           order by hitnumber
           rows between unbounded preceding and current row
          ) as t_id
from q1 join
     q2 using (session_id);
```

The difference from your answer is the windowing clause which ends at the current row.

EDIT:

It looks like there is one `t_id` per `session_id`, so just use `max()`:

```
select . . . ,
       max(transaction_id) over (partition by session_id) as t_id
from q1 join
     q2 using (session_id);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I have tried this but still not getting the output I want, I have updated my question to show the results of this updated query.